# How to combine mvn clean and mvn install into a single task?

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven

I'm following the [Scala, Eclipse and Maven Integration tutorial](http://blog.samibadawi.com/2011/07/scala-eclipse-and-maven-integration.html).
It is really useful.
But there is one thing that seems annoying to me:
I always need to run two commands from the Eclipse **Run as** menu:

```
Maven clean
Maven install
```

Is there any way to configure Scala and Maven plugins for Eclipse, to make it possible **to run both tasks as a single command** from the Eclipse menu?

For example:

```
Maven clean install
```

like in the [following Eclipse non-Scala configuration](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-the-maven-clean-phase.html?page=2).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Choose the option *Maven build...*, and type `clean install` in the *Goals* text box.